# Create data from the Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to create a data with the console on an model in db.

This is the model:

```
class CreateBancas < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :bancas do |t|
      t.string :nome
      t.string :cognome
      t.integer :numero
      t.integer :scadenza
      t.integer :type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

When i do an query like this:

```
Banca.create!(:nome => "eric", :cognome => "noumedem", :scadenza => "2016", :numero => "123", :type => "1")
```

i have some error like so:

```
ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: Invalid single-table inheritance type: 1 is not a subclass of Banca
    from /home/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:178:in `subclass_from_attrs'
    from /home/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:22:in `new'
    from /home/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/validations.rb:39:in `create!'
    from (irb):307
    from /home/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: **This is my assumption** I believe Rails doesn't like you using column name `type` on a model. If you do, you will have to add this to your model. `self.inheritance_column = nil`. Again, I could be wrong, but I believe this should work. Someone else may be able to explain better than I can.

Comment: The use of the field `type` is the issue i think.  Rather than configure your model to allow the `type` field, as @Justin suggests, i'd recommend just keeping life simple and using a different name for the field.

Comment: I also agree with @MaxWilliams. If this is a new app, without a lot of data, go ahead and just change the column name.

Comment: Rails expects column `type` for STI, and should be a string.

Comment: While these column names are optional, they are in fact reserved by Active Record. Steer clear of reserved keywords unless you want the extra functionality. For example, type is a reserved keyword used to designate a table using Single Table Inheritance (STI). If you are not using STI, try an analogous keyword like "context", that may still accurately describe the data you are modeling. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions

Comment: I also agree with all of you. I rename column type. Now it is work very well. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Change `:type` column name to something else, eg. `:kind`, `:role` or `:banca_type`:

**Here is the code:**

```
rails g migration renameTypeColumnInBancasToKind

#db/migrate/renameTypeColumnInBancasToKind.rb

class CreateBancas < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def up
     rename_column :bancas, :type, :kind
   end

   def down
     rename_column :bancas, :kind, type
   end
end
```

**And here is why it happens:**

In Rails `:type` name of column is reserved for [STI (Single Table Inheritance)](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance) - if you want to fill `:type` column with value "1", rails automatically try to create model which class_name is exactly like the value of this column.

So, when you write:

```
Banca.create!(:type => "1")
```

It means exactly that:

```
1.create!
```

You have not Class named "1", so there is source of this error. Best practice to use type attribute in your class is to create one get method and one put method for that.

```
#app/models/banca.rb
def type
  kind
end

def type=(value)
  kind = value
end
```

Hope it will help, vote if so :)